# Galaxy S21 - remove video call shortcut when ending a call

Tags: samsung, settings

When ending a call, there's a video call shortcut button which appears - is there a way to turn this off - see the lower right of the screenshot below which is what shows when the call is over.  I never use it at this time and occasionally I've accidentally hit it.

[image]